# Embedded Widget Not Clicking On Laravel After Being Successfully Added

Tags: laravel, web, iframe, widget, laravel-blade

I have been trying hard to embedded some widgets on my laravel website but after it has been successfully added, it will show up on the website but non of the links on the embedded widget would click.

```
<iframe src="https://bit2me.com/widget/buy/v2?currency=BTC&amount=200&method=card" style="display:block;width:100%;max-width:360px;height:530px;margin:0 auto;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

That's one of the widget I've been trying to add.

Actually I know very little about web development but I tried many things I could see online.

I just need some great suggestion on what might be wrong.

Comment: That the issue might be caused by a conflict with your website's CSS or JavaScript, or some security restrictions applied by your Laravel application or the browser.